# Bitwise operation >>> in python?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I receive a piece of code written in java, that uses the operation `>>>`, after a quick search, I found out that it ["shifts a zero into the leftmost position"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), but I could not find a equal operation [in python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

What would be the similar operation for the following code in python?

```java
((CRC & 0xFF00) >>> 8)
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-bitwise-operators/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that python's `>>` is identical to Java's `>>>`, and it doesn't have a signed bitshift (which copies the most significant bit when shifting, rather than using 0)

Comment: In Python, `CRC & 0xFF00` would be equivalent to `CRC & 0x0FF00`. IIRC, if you wanted sign extension, you would do `CRC & 0x1FF00` to get an appropriately sign-extended result from the following `>>`.

Comment: python docs for [bitwise operations on integers types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know python's `>>` does exactly that (what java's `>>>` does). and the `&` does the same is python as in java.

```
(CRC & 0xFF00) >> 8
```